# jquery onclick setting variable

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-click-event, input-field

I set a variable 'api_key' on document load. I want to modify this variable with the text of an input field after clicking a button

```
var api_key = "";

//my button has an id named "btn-verify", the input field has an id named "verify"
$("#btn-verify").click({
        api_key = $("#verify").val();

    });
```

this doesn't work, how should I fix this. How do I assign api_key to the value of the input field, on click of a button

Comment: Try wrapping your click handler inside `document.ready`. -- `$(function () { $("#btn-verify").click({  api_key = $("#verify").val(); }); });`

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: @Justin I get "Unexpected token (" or "Unexpected token ="

Comment: @CQM I'm with Vega.  It probably is executing before the the document is finished loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the function declaration when binding the handler.

Change

```
$("#btn-verify").click({
```

to

```
//Missing function declaration--v   
  $("#btn-verify").click(function (){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-verify").click(function(){
        api_key = $("#verify").val();
    });
});
```

the ready function will cause JS to wait untill the DOM finishes to load before runing.